# How to control max response size

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, iis-6

I have a web application I support that have sometimes huge web pages to render.

Sometimes I have this exception (it is **not** linked to an *upload* the user make, the webpage render about 22MB of Html):

```
Error Caught in Page : http://example.com/thepage.aspx
Error Message:Maximum request length exceeded.
Stack Trace:   at System.Web.HttpRequest.GetEntireRawContent()
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.FillInFormCollection()
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_Form()
   at System.Web.HttpRequest.get_HasForm()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.GetCollectionBasedOnMethod(Boolean dontReturnNull)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.DeterminePostBackMode()
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint
```

I tried to use `maxRequestLength` property of `HttpRuntime` node in web.config but it doesn't seem to control that.

As test case I tried to set it to 5K but the webpage shows even if it's bigger (it's around 150K) so I guess it will not permit to show huge webpages.

Is there a way I can control maximum response size and avoid the "Maximum request length exceeded" error ?

If it changes anything we are using .Net 4.0 with IIS 6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `Response.Buffer=false` for that page, and use the `Response.Flush()` time to time as you render your page.

This way you can avoid to render all data at ones to the buffer and wait this buffer to full before send it.

Also disable the viewstate on the controls that you do not needed.

If the above can not solve the issue then you need to redesign your page using a different type of control that allow them and you can send data to the browser time to time using the fluah(). A repeater control can work, maybe a gridview may not work.

Comment: Nice idea I am not sure if it will really solve the problem since it is a series of GridView(maybe to a flush per GridView) but I will do some tests. Since it's legacy I have limited action possible but it seems feasible.

Comment: @Erick focus on the buffer=false, and on viewstate to turn it off.

Comment: Sounds like something that works. Page has gone from 22Mb to 4.61MB(!). It's not a setting but kind of help for legacy-ish software. :-)

Comment: @Erick Something works from what I write or randomly ? I lost you :)

Comment: Well desactivating the ViewState and Flushing helped.